# Can't copy value from Excel to Word vba

Tags: vba

How to copy defined Range **from Excel** and past it **to Word**? Code below copy text as a Table, but I want to copy it as a text (**Value**) with my format of font without table.
Tried to use **.PastSpecial** in different ways, but result DEBUG. Maybe someone knows solution?

```
Sub Word()

   Dim objWord

   Dim objDoc

   Dim objSelection

   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

   objWord.Visible = True

   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection


    Range("B51:B60").Copy

    With objDoc.Paragraphs(objDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
           'All formatting goes here
        .Paste
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Color = black
        .Font.Size = 11

    End With

    objDoc.SaveAs ("D:\MyFirstSave")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could get the last created table and act on it with `ConvertToText()` method:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Word()
    With CreateObject("Word.Application") ' create and reference a word application object
        .Visible = True ' make referenced object visible
        With .Documents.Add ' create and reference a new document of referenced word obejct
            Range("B51:B60").Copy ' copy the wanted Excel range
            With .Paragraphs(.Paragraphs.Count).Range ' reference referenced document last paragrapgh range
                .Paste
                .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
                .Font.Color = vbBlack
                .Font.Size = 11
            End With
            .tables(.tables.Count).ConvertToText(Separator:=0).ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0  ' wdSeparateByParagraphs = 0 and  wdAlignParagraphLeft = 0

            .SaveAs ("D:\MyFirstSave")
            .Close
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this?

```
Option Explicit
Const wdFormatPlainText As Long = 22
Public Sub Copy2Word()
    Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

    objWord.Visible = True

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B51:B60").Copy

    With objDoc.Paragraphs(objDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
        .PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
        .Font.NAME = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With
    'Other code
End Sub
```

---

[Word enumerated constants](https://documentation.help/MS-Office-Word-VB/wohowConstants.htm).

Comment: This variant gives the same result as my code, it past text in Word with table.

Comment: It doesn't paste as a table for me. How is your source data formatted? Is it a table?

Comment: Yes, source data formatted as a table. I'm using Microsoft Office 2013, maybe it influence for something.